# Get the newest revision of certain group in SQL + Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a table with different kind of jobs. The structure is like this:

```
id
job_id
rev
[other fields]
```

So each time a job is edited a new line is added to database, it has a unique id, the job_id is the same as last time (since the job is the same but just edited) and the rev number is bigger( 1 -> 2).

Now i would like to display these jobs in a table, id like to get the data so that its grouped with the job_id and the newest revision is shown.

Example:

```
1    53kjA7    1     This is a job
2    Adf98A    1     Another job
3    53kjA7    2     This is a job edited
4    8123Ag    1     More jobs
5    Adf98A    2     Another job edited
```

And the table would show:

```
3    53kjA7    2    This is a job edited
5    Adf98A    2     Another job edited
4    8123Ag    1     More jobs
```

Im using codeigniter and its built in active record, i have tried it like this:

```
$this->db->select()->from('jobs')->group_by('job_id')->select_max('rev');
```

But the result is a table that shows the grouped jobs with the newest revision number, but all other info is from another job from same group, like this:

```
1    53kjA7    2     This is a job
2    Adf98A    2     Another job
4    8123Ag    1     More jobs
```

Is there a way of doing this with the active record or do i need to make a custom SQL string?

Comment: I could be wrong with this, but for starters try changing the order of `select_max` and `group_by`.

Comment: still not working, actually the result is same :/

Comment: This is a common problem with sql - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thoughts. What does your join look like to the other table (I suspect the join might be off)? And an order_by might be needed in order to get the latest revisions.

Comment: This kind of response would be better posted as a comment.  Adding an answer to a question significantly decreases the chances that someone else will come along and answer it.

Comment: If I had the rep to add a comment I would have done as such..but as you'll see I haven't reach 50 rep...I can't post a comment on that string...:) Can post a comment on a answer that I post however!